# Ratingbar with custom images in android/Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, ratingbar

[Image of custom ratingbar]

[Is it possible to create a custom rating bar like this? If yes, can you give me an example on how to do it in Andorid/kotlin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/943Wo.png)

**Is it possible to create a custom rating bar like this? If yes, can you give me an example on how to do it in Andorid/kotlin**
i am already try with custom rating with style.`

```
 <style name="CustomRatingBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/customrating</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">15dip</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">15dip</item>
    </style>
```

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/rating_empty"/>

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/rating_empty"
        />
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/rating_fill"
        />

</layer-list>
```